# How can I hide parameters and show the message "missing data", in an RDL report?

Tags: reporting-services, rdl

I'm building one report, using SSRS 2016, like this:

- Parameter **Country**: populated by a DataSet.
- Parameter **Region**: populated by a DataSet.

```
   ________________________________
  | Parameter Country selection | v |
  |---------------------------------|
  | Parameter Region selection  | v |
  |_________________________________|
   _________________________
  | My Report               |
  |  ____________________   |
  | | Nome     | Cognome |  |
  | |----------|---------|  |
  | | Mario    | Rossi   |  |
  | | Giuseppe | Verdi   |  |
  |  ...                    |
```

If the DataSet **country** is empty, I would like the report to hide the parameters and all the report's elements (tables, labels, etc.) and show one default message, like following:

```
   _________________________
  | My Report               |
  |                         |
  | Missing data.           |
  |                         |
  |                         |
  |  ...                    |
```

Can you help me?
Thanks

Comment: You won't be able to hide the params but you could use the folowing as the visible expression for your report controls. iif(Rownumber("Dataset_Name")=0, false,true).

Comment: Hi Snowlockk, there is a way to create one "container"  with all my report's element so that I can set only one expression on report? Thanks

Comment: You can try putting it in a rectangle I think setting visible to false should hide the internal controls as well.

Comment: Hi, Now I try your solution. Thanks.